# How to get latest post id

Tags: blogger

How to find latest blogger post id in javascript. manipulate post id automatically

```
<script>
  function handleResponse(response) {
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML += "<h1>" + response.title + "</h1>";
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<h1>" + response.content + "</h1>";
  }
</script>

<script src="https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/2057990476459552980/posts/post Id?callback=handleResponse&key=key"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get data of the latest post, you can do :

```html
<div id="title"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
  function handleResponse(response) {
   var post = response.feed.entry[0];
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML += "<h1>" + post.title.$t + "</h1>";
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<h1>" + post.content.$t + "</h1>";
  }
</script>

<script src="https://www.blogger.com/feeds/2057990476459552980/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&max-results=1&callback=handleResponse"></script>
```

**Updated:**

In order to get multiple posts, you can start with this code. Change `max-results` parameter to control posts number

```html
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
  function handleResponse(response) {
   var page = "";
   var posts = response.feed.entry;
   for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
    page +=  "<div><h2>" + posts[i].title.$t + "</h2>" + posts[i].content.$t + "<div>";
   }
   document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = page;
  }
</script>

<script src="https://www.blogger.com/feeds/2057990476459552980/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&max-results=5&callback=handleResponse"></script>
```

Comment: but only one field fetch, i want to multiple field fetch

Comment: Glad it helped! Please, consider accepting my answer. See answer update